# how to toggle the child element class using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

on click on anchor how to toggle the child span element classes?

I already have one click function on my anchor: on click how to togle "glyphicon-chevron-down" to "glyphicon-chevron-up" ?

```
    <a ng-click="toggleList()">
     View More <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have

**Markup**

```
<a ng-click="toggleList()">
     View More <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="getClass()"></span>
</a>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.toggleList = function(){
   //other logic here
   $scope.isDown = !$scope.isDown; 
}

$scope.getClass = function(){
    return $scope.isDown ? 'glyphicon-chevron-down': 'glyphicon-chevron-up';
}
```

Comment: It not works: by default it comes with 'up' but on click its not toggling!! :) <a ng-click="toggleList(isDown)">
     View More <span class="glyphicon" class="glyphicon" ng-class="getClass(isDown)"></span>
</a>

Comment: are we need to keep this $scope.getClass within the toggleList function ?

Comment: @Krish `$scope` is basically used for binding and then you can use scope variable on html directly in angular directives.